# Как правильно использовать QMediaMetaData для определения параметров медиафайлов?

Tags: c++, qt, media

Подскажите, как мне определить параметры аудиофайла при помощи QMediaMetaData: битрейт, частоту дискретизации, битовую глубину, формат.
Мне нужно получить эти параметры из существующего файла для последующего перекодирования аудиофайла в другой формат. Я пытался использовать QMediaMetaData таким образом (при том не знаю правильно ли я использовал так же QMediaObject):

```
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaMetaData>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaObject>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
.
.
.
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_1_clicked()
{
   QMediaObject mediafile;
   QString file_name = "/run/media/helg/WDC/test.aac";   
   mediafile.setMedia(QUrl(file_name));
   QString bitrate = mediafile.metaData(QMediaMetaData::AudioBitRate).toString();
   .
   .
   .
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: На данном этапе программа естественно выдает ошибки на этапе компиляции, я даже не уверен на правильном ли я пути.